# Is it possible to send transaction in Polygon-mumbai using web3 and ethereumjs-tx?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, polygon

```
const main = async () =>{
    const abi = fs.readFileSync('erc20_abi.json', 'utf-8')
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), contractAddress);
    const transfer = contract.methods.transfer("0xDd63848C3A3582702B56c977480C12CCb14c6A0A", web3.utils.toHex(10e18));
    const encodedABI = transfer.encodeABI();

    const rawTransaction = {
        from: senderAddress,
        to: contractAddress,
        gas: 2000000,
        data: encodedABI
    };
    
    const privKey = Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex');

    const customChainParams = { name: 'matic-mumbai', chainId: 80001, networkId: 80001 }
    const common = Common.default.forCustomChain('goerli',customChainParams)

    const tx = new Tx(rawTransaction, {common });
    tx.sign(privKey);
    const serializedTx = tx.serialize();

    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
    console.log(receipt)
}
```

I am getting an error Method called with neither a hardfork set nor provided by param.
Can someone please assist as to what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `custom()` constructor & `CustomChain` enum provided by `@ethereumjs/common`

Install the package:

```
npm i @ethereumjs/common
```

Code Sample to use Polygon-Mumbai Network:

```
// require    
const { Common, CustomChain } = require("@ethereumjs/common");
const ethJs = require("ethereumjs-tx");

const common = Common.custom(CustomChain.PolygonMumbai);
// use the network in transaction
const tx = new ethJs.Transaction(rawTransaction, { common });
```